# How to add multiple textbox controls using a loop and change ID

Tags: asp.net

" runat="server" />

But this code is not working
How can I add multiple controls using loops by this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the <%= %> syntax cannot be used within tag bodies or attributes in ASP.NET. The <%= notation is a shorthand for Response.Write() - and so is limited in where it can be used.

What you can do instead, in your situation, is use the `<asp:CheckBoxList>` control. It provides better direct support for what you're trying to do, without the awkwardness.

Comment: Documentation for the CheckBoxList control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use server controls in this way. You can easily render the `<input>` HTML element yourself though.

```
<%
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
%>
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox<%=i %>" name="Checkbox<%= i %>" />
<%
  }
%>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want though, as you should handle the input manually using `Request.Form`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that shows how to create dynamic controls:

[Creating dynamic controls using ASP.NET 2.0 and C# .NET](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/control-dym-aspnet2-csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question:
[How do I dynamically create new Hyperlinks in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947973/how-do-i-dynamically-create-new-hyperlinks-in-asp-net)