# How to insert <a href> tag in the table in asp.net in code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dynamically create new Hyperlinks in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947973/how-do-i-dynamically-create-new-hyperlinks-in-asp-net)

I am adding tables dynamically in my code. i want to add this  using coding in my code behind file. My code is given below:

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td class="what-to-expect">
        <a href="#TB_inline?height=200&width=300&inlineId=myOnPageContent" title="add a caption to title attribute" class="thickbox">?</a>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone tell me how to add this through code?

**code added from comments**

```
HtmlTableRow trContent = new HtmlTableRow(); 
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell(); 
cell1.InnerText = SomeTextHere; 
trContent.Cells.Add(cell1)
```

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: What part are you trying to add? Is the part dynamically driven from the results?

Comment: I want to add <a herf tag dynamcially. cause i am adding all my controls dynamically. i.e. table,tr,td and all the controls which is inside the td.

Comment: If you can post some of the code which you have that is dynamically creating this? We can then see what it is you need.

Comment: I am adding controls by using following code and in that i want to add controls dynamically like dropdown, text box,list box etc.....                           HtmlTableRow trContent = new HtmlTableRow();
                HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                cell1.InnerText = SomeTextHere;
                trContent.Cells.Add(cell1);

Comment: Don't add as a comment, edit your question with the code.

Comment: HtmlTableRow trContent = new HtmlTableRow(); HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell(); cell1.InnerText = SomeTextHere; trContent.Cells.Add(cell1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is add a `HyperLink` control to your Cell

```
HtmlTableRow trContent = new HtmlTableRow(); 
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell(); 
HyperLink hl = new HyperLink() 
{ 
    Text = "?", 
    NavigateUrl = "#TB_inline?height=200&width=300&inlineId=myOnPageContent",
    CssClass="thickbox", 
    ToolTip = "add a caption to title attribute" 
};
cell1.Controls.Add(hl); 
trContent.Cells.Add(cell1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a HyperLink object in code, assign all the relevant data to it, then add it to the relevant cell.

So something like

```
Dim link As New HyperLink()
link.NavigateURL = "#TB_inline?height=200&width=300&inlineId=myOnPageContent"
link.ToolTip = "add a caption to title attribute"
link.CssClass = "thickbox"
link.Text = "?"

cell1.Controls.Add(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<asp:literal runat="server" id="lblSomething" />`.

Then in your code behind, write something like this:

```
lblSomething.Text = "<your table code>";
```