# Creating <asp:Hyperlink> in Code Behind, but not displaying when running

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am creating my web page dynamically because the data is always changing.

I have a row that has columns with a hyperlink.  If I view in browser without using my code behind, it works perfectly.  When I try to run from code behind, the link doesn't show.  Only the back color of the

Here is the code behind where I create the row

```
strTable += "<tr id=""Row1_EventName"" style=""height: 19pt; width:100%"" runat=""server"">"
    strTable += "<td id=""Elem1_Name"" runat=""server"" colspan=""16"" class=""xl6620798"" style=""width:48.48%"">"
    strTable += "<asp:HyperLink runat=""server"" NavigateUrl=""" & strElem1_ChartLink & """ Text=""" & strElem1_Name & """ ToolTip=""" & strElem1_EventDirectionDesc & """ ForeColor=""Blue"" Width=""100%"" />"
    strTable += "</td>"
    strTable += "<td Class=""xl1520798"" style=""width:3.03%""></td>"

    If strElem2_Name <> "" Then
        strTable += "<td id=""Elem2_Name"" runat=""server"" colspan=""16"" class=""xl6620798"" style=""width:48.48%"">"
        strTable += "<asp:HyperLink runat = ""server"" NavigateUrl=""" & strElem2_ChartLink & """ Text=""" & strElem2_Name & """ ToolTip=""" & strElem2_EventDirectionDesc & """ ForeColor=""Blue"" Width=""100%"" />"
        strTable += "</td>"
    Else
        strTable += "<td colspan=""16"" class=""xl1520798"" style=""width:48.48%""></td>"
    End If

    strTable += "</tr>"
```

The css code is below:

```
.xl1520798 {
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-right: 1px;
        padding-left: 1px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 9.0pt;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .xl6620798 {
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-right: 1px;
        padding-left: 1px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 9.0pt;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        background: #B8CCE4;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Below is what it looks like when I run the page:

[Hyperlink not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipv7E.png)

Comment: What you are doing now will never work. You are not creating an `asp:hyperlink`, but just a string. If you want to add controls from code behind you will have to create and add Controls dynamically.

Comment: This link should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947973/how-do-i-dynamically-create-new-hyperlinks-in-asp-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically create new Hyperlinks in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947973/how-do-i-dynamically-create-new-hyperlinks-in-asp-net)

Comment: It has been working except instead of a Hyperlink, I was using the <a></a> with the same information.  The additional code further down was "divMarketSnapshot.InnerHtml = strTable"; which takes the entire string and places it into the <div>

Comment: Thank you for the responses about creating the Hyperlink controls.  The only issue is that I only have the <div></div> on the page and I create the entire table in code behind; which includes adding the hyperlinks.  The only reason that I changed to the hyperlink is because there wasn't a tooltip for the <a href=>.  If you know of a way to create the tooltip for this, then I am open to your suggestions.  Thanks